# What does it mean for the question vote counts to look "folded"?

Tags: support, design, meta

[image]

What do those "folds" mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not a fold. It's a diagonal green stripe indicating that the question has an accepted answer.

Comment: Oh, ok. Thanks. This question will be green in 6 minutes : ) .